# An infinite union of closed sets is a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

**Question**: {$B_n$}$ \in \Bbb R$ is a family of closed sets.
Prove that $\cup _{n=1}^\infty B_n$ is not necessarily a closed set.

**What I thought**: Using a counterexample: If I say that each $B_i$ is a set of all numbers in range $[i,i+1]$ then I can pick a sequence $a_n \in \cup _{n=1}^\infty B_n$ s.t. $a_n \to \infty$ (because eventually the set includes all positive reals) and since $\infty \notin \Bbb R$ then $\cup _{n=1}^\infty B_n$ is not a closed set.

Is this proof correct?
Thanks

Comment: The notation $\{B_n\} \in \Bbb R$ is not correct. You probably meant that $\{B_n\}$ is a family/sequence of closed sets and each $B_n\subseteq\Bbb R$, i.e., each of the sets is a subset of real line.

Comment: What might be interesting to notice (although it might be a little too advanced, if this is your first course in topology) that the family of sets in your example is [locally finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection#Closed_sets). Union of a locally finite system of closed sets is again a closed set.

Comment: Let $B_n=\{\frac 1 n\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, then $\bigcup B_n=\{\frac 1 n: n\in N^+\}$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The set containing all the reals *is* a closed set.  infinity is not a point in in the universe so it is not a limit point of a_n.  a_n -> c has c being a limit point only if c is finite.  Hint:  Let a_n -> 0 but not have 0 in any of the sets. Let B_i = [a_n, something] and a_n -> 0.  then what happens?

Comment: For future visitors: this can be true under some extra conditions, like the family of closed sets that one is taking the union over being locally finite. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2269119/405572, or https://planetmath.org/theunionofalocallyfinitecollectionofclosedsetsisclosed, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider the topological space (subspace of$\mathbb{R}$ (real numbers) with the usual topology given by $\epsilon$-neighborhood) given by
$$\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$$
Then, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ the subset 
$$\{\frac{1}{n}\}$$is both open and closed, but the countable union 
$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n>0}\{\frac{1}{n}\}$$ is precisely the set
$$\{\frac{1}{n}:n>0\}$$
which is not closed, for example because $0$ lies in its closure, but not in the set itself.

Answer (score 55):

Every subset of $\mathbb R^ n$ is a union of closed sets, namely, the one-point sets consisting of each one of its points.

Yet not all subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are closed!

Comment: I had a typo....

Comment: That's a nice proof. +1

Comment: Does not $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}B_n$ not imply countable union? In that sense $\mathbb{R}^n$ would not qualify.

Comment: @user57 thankfully there are countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not closed.

Comment: Ah, yes sure. Sorry.

Answer (score 25):

Think of the union of the $B_{n} = [1/n, 1]$.

Comment: is there a major difference between [i,i+1] and [\frac 1n,1]?

Comment: I'm sorry but could you elaborate on why $[i, i+1]$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology?

Comment: Sorry all, I thought I had seen parentheses instead of brackets. Better check my spectacles. Apologies.

Comment: This is a good example. If we let $n$ begin from $2$, the result will be $(0,1]$, which is not closed.

Answer (score 6):

But since $\infty\notin\Bbb R$ we cannot use it as a counterexample. To see that is indeed the case note that your union is the set $[1,\infty)$, which is closed. Why is it closed? Recall that $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is closed if and only if every *convergent* sequence $a_n$ whose elements are from $A$, has a limit inside $A$. So we need sequences whose limits are real numbers to begin with, and so sequences converging to $\infty$ are of no use to us. On the other hand, if $a_n\geq 1$ then their limit is $\geq 1$, so $[1,\infty)$ is closed.

You need to try this with bounded intervals whose union is bounded. Show that in such case the result is an open interval.

Another option is to note that $\{a\}$ is closed, but $\Bbb Q$ is the union of countably many closed sets. Is $\Bbb Q$ closed?

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, $\bigcup B_i = [1,\infty)$. But this is a closed set so it does not provide a counter example.

Consider $B_n = [0, 1 - \frac{1}{n}]$. Then every $x \in [0,1)$ is in $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N_{>0}} B_n$. But what about the end point $1$?

Answer (score 5):

The way I do this is by first proving that the countable intersection of open sets need not be open by this counterexample: $$\bigcap_{\infty}\left (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right) = \left\{ {0} \right\} $$ Then because a closed set is the complement of an open set we get that the countable union of closed sets need not be closed because $$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right)^c=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i^c\;.$$