# The infinite union of closed sets is closed?

Tags: general-topology

**Question:**

I need to show that

$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [2n, 2n+1]$ is closed.

I thought that in order for the union of closed sets to be closed it must be a finite union. Since I can take a sequence

$x_k = 2k, $ then $x_k \to \infty $ as $ k \to \infty$ Since $\{x_k\} \subseteq A$ $ \forall$ $ k \in \Bbb{N} $ so $x_k $ does not converge, then $A$ is open.

Apparently something is wrong with my understanding.

Comment: A finite union of closed set is always closed. An infinite union *can* be closed, but that is not necessarily true.

Also your proof attempt makes me think you're confusing the notion of "closed set" and "compact set".

Comment: Ok, So to show A is closed I can just argue that the intersection of $A$ and a ball around any $x \in A$ is nonempty

Comment: I'll direct you to @Eric Wofsey 's answer for more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several misunderstandings here.  Let's go through them one by one.

First, in a topological space, any finite union of closed sets is closed.  It is *not necessarily the case* that an infinite union of closed sets is closed.  However, it is entirely possible that in some particular examples, an infinite union of closed sets might be closed.  As an example, if $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ is any infinite closed set, then $B$ is the union of all the singleton sets $\{x\}$ where $x\in B$.  These singletons are closed, so $B$ is an infinite union of closed sets which is closed.

Second, for your set $A$ to be closed, you need to know that whenever $(x_k)$ is a sequence of points in $A$ *which converges to some limit $x\in\mathbb{R}$*, $x\in A$ as well.  Your example sequence does not converge to any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so that's OK.  You only need the limit of a sequence to be in $A$ when the limit exists in $\mathbb{R}$ to begin with.

Third, "open" and "not closed" do not mean the same thing.  So even if you found that $A$ is not closed, that would not mean that it is open.  A set is open iff its *complement* is closed, and a set is closed iff its complement is open.

In fact, in this case, the easiest way to prove your set $A$ is closed may be to prove that its complement is open.  Think about what $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ looks like and see if you can write it as a union of open intervals.

Comment: If we assume $\mathbb{R}$ to be the topological space is the following true? We know that if $A$ contains all its limit points then it is closed. Let be $a^*$ such a limit point, then its neigbourhood $N:=\{a\in \mathbb{R}\mid|a-a^*|<\frac{1}{2}\}$ contains a point $a\in A\implies a\in [2n_0,2n_0+1]$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$. If we shrink the neighbourhood of $a^*$ we still find another $a'\in[2n_0,2n_0+1]$. Hence, $a^*$ is a limit point of $[2n_0,2n_0+1]$ and because $[2n_0,2n_0+1]$ is closed it follows that $a^*\in[2n_0,2n_0+1]$. So, $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a union of finitely many closed sets is closed does not imply that the union of an infinite number of closed sets is *not* closed.

As a trivial example, consider an infinite union of closed sets, all of which are equal.

In your case, to show that the given union is closed, just express the complement as a union of open intervals.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that an infinite union of closed sets is closed, there are cases (like these) were they are: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of closed sets of a space $X$ that is locally finite (which means that every $x \in X$ has an open neighbourhood $O_x$ such that $\{C \in \mathcal{C}: C \cap O_x \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite). Then $\bigcup \mathcal{C}$ is closed.

Proof: let $x \notin C = \bigcup \mathcal{C}$. Then find $O_x$ as promised by local finiteness. The set $\mathcal{C}_x = \{C \in \mathcal{C}: O_x \cap C \neq \emptyset \}$ is a finite collection of closed sets. So $C' = \bigcup \mathcal{C}_x$ is closed and $x$ is not in it, so $(X \setminus C')\cap O_x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ that misses all of $C$ (it misses all members of $\mathcal{C}_x$ by being a subset of $X \setminus C'$ and all other members of $\mathcal{C}$ as it's a subset of  $O_x$ as well) So all points that are not in $C$ are not in its closure. This means $C$ is indeed closed.

Now it's easy to check that the collection $\{[2n, 2n+1]: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is locally finite: either $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\ge 2$ and then it lies in some $[2n,2n+1]$ and then $O_x =(x-\frac{1}{2}, x + \frac{1}{2})$ will do, or $x \ge 2 $ and it lies in some $(2n+1 ,2n)$, which itself will do as its $O_x$. For all other $x$ use $O_x =(-\infty ,2)$

Answer (score 0):

The union of a finite number of closed sets is *known* to be closed by assumption, but this does not prevent the union of a infinite number of closed from being closed.

In your case $A = \mathbb{RR}^+$ which is an unbounded and closed set.

Your argument breaks because the sequence does not converge to a point.